# Zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed

Tags: r

I followed the code here: https://rpubs.com/simaan84/covid19 to run two codes as follow:

```
ds_covid <- as.xts(apply(DS_t10,1,sum))
ds_covid_1 <- ds_covid/lag(ds_covid)-1
```

But I had the error:

```
zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed
```

Please help me.

Comment: Since it appears `ds_covid` is a time series, try clarifying which `lag` you are using, probably want `stats::lag()`. Try `ds_covid_1 <- ds_covid/stats::lag(ds_covid)-1`. The example looks like it is using other packages.

Comment: Thank you emccracke. I could do it. Cheers.

Comment: NP @Mandy - it´s my job ;)

Comment: @Mandy to help the quality of your question and the answers try posting an example that can run completely independently as per SO guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `dplyr` loaded, by chance? That's the only way I can replicate your error.

`dplyr` masks the `stats::lag()` generic function that ships with base R. That breaks method dispatch for all S3 classes that define a `lag()` method. So, that means `lag()` may or may not work for those classes.

So you either need to:

1. Not load `dplyr`
2. Explicitly call `stats::lag()` everywhere you don't want to use `dplyr::lag()`

Comment: Great suggestion, but without a replicable example it's pretty much looking in a crystal ball to guess what Ops issue is IMHO. Trying to replicate an error is just throwing dart's blindly.