# Zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed -- explanation

Tags: r, quantmod

Need explanation why do I get error *Zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed* when I am trying to use lag() function on a time series data.

Also, after going through thread [Zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607850/zero-length-vectors-with-non-zero-length-index-are-not-allowed) and using the suggestion stats::lag(X,1) worked completely fine. Request to please explain what/how stats:: helps in solving the problem.

Comment: There is a function called `lag` in `dplyr`. If you have loaded `dplyr`, then the version of `lag` that is used is the version from `dplyr`. Although it has the same name as the function `lag` in the `stats` package, it is a completely different function and gives you an error when you try to use it on your data. To specify that you want the function `lag` from the `stats` package, you need to use the _namespace identifier_ `stats::lag`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is related to masking of `lag` from other packages.  `lag` is one function which can get masked from packages like `dplyr` i.e. when we load the `dplyr`, it shows

```
library(dplyr)

#Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

#The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

#    filter, lag
```

The `lag` mentioned in that link needs the `stats::lag` and not the `dplyr::lag`.  So, when we use a different `lag`, the behavior also changes

```
stats::lag(1:5, 1) # // not removing the observation but create attribute
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#attr(,"tsp")
#[1] 0 4 1
dplyr::lag(1:5, 1) # // by default removes the last and append NA
#[1] NA  1  2  3  4
```